# Why is there a SpreadsheetApp. open() function but not a DocumentApp.open()?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs

When I test this script;

```
function loop() {
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('actualIDhere');
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while(files.hasNext()){
        var doc = DocumentApp.open(files.next());
        ...
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function open in object DocumentApp. (line 5, file "Code")

A google apps spreadsheet analog (from which I took it) would seem to work (see here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

```
// Get any starred spreadsheets from Google Drive, then open the spreadsheets
// and log the name of the first sheet within each spreadsheet.

var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('starred = true and mimeType = "' + MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS + '"');
while (files.hasNext()) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(files.next());
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
    Logger.log(sheet.getName());
}
```

Any ideas why this fails and what code to replace it with?

Comment: Review `DocumentApp` documentation. What're the methods available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think that:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.open(files.next());
```

should rather be:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(files.next().getId());
```

because a `fileId` is the expected parameter there.

Comment: Is there some other method that works, because as noted, still getting error (TypeError: Cannot find function open in object DocumentApp. (line 5, file "Code")
) on "open".

Answer (score 1):

The available methods for DocumentApp are listed on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app.

There isn't an `open` method but there are two methods to open a document:

- `openById(id)`
- `openByUrl(url)`

Since `files.next()` returns a [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) object which has the methods:

- `getId()`
- `getUrl()`

it's up to you which DocumentApp method to use.